# MS-DOS source code debugging in bochs. Looping problem

Tags: assembly, dos, x86-16, bootloader, bochs

I am running MS-DOS 5.0 boot code in bochs and it gets stuck in following loop. I don't know when will it break. What is it trying to do.

```
7BA3:
MOV AL, BYTE PTR DS:0X0040
MOV BYTE PTR SS:[BP-15], AL
MOV AL, BYTE PTR SS:[BP-15]
TEST AL,AL
JNZ [7BA2]
---------------------------
---------------------------
7BA2: 
MOV AL, BYTE PTR 
DS:0X003E
AND AL, 0X80
MOV BYTE PTR SS:[BP-15], AL
MOV AL, BYTE PTR SS:[BP-15]
TEST AL, AL
JZ [7B73]
```

Comment: What's the value of DS at this point?

Comment: Also, I think you've left out some important instructions, because what's here is not a loop.

Comment: If DS=0040h, this may be doing some stuff with the floppy drive, see [Ralf Brown's Memory List](https://github.com/cirosantilli/ralf-brown-interrupt-list/blob/fde1a5ac1b7e8a45ff4255ee275ee77c7fe7e256/inter61c/MEMORY.LST#L403).  I don't know exactly what, though.

Comment: Are you sure this is even MS-DOS bootcode. I find it highly suspicious and am surprised that it is executing code at 0x7ba3 below where the normal bootloader is loaded.